Pdf with a box to sign it with a digital certificate
Good afternoon, I am doing an internship and I need a pdf with a box to sign it with a digital certificate, but I can't find it anywhere. IF anyone had some proof.
Many thanks

There is nothing especial about PDF signing, compared to other text or image signatures on paper. It is just a box, so you can write a working copy in notepad.

The "Key" feature to applying a PDF signature is use the Adobe ISO standard digital design feature as designed for PDF or paper printouts.
Scanned or electronic can be any source, so here PLAIN TEXT is read by Adobe Acrobat Reader and the signature can be stamped by Adobe Reader Signing, or via the web, or any one of its clones.
Here is the coded text as text.pdf
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj<</AcroForm 2 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>endobj
2 0 obj<</DR<</Font<</Helv 4 0 R>>>>/Fields[5 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Count 1/Kids[6 0 R]/Type/Pages>>endobj
4 0 obj<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding 7 0 R/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>endobj
5 0 obj<</AP<</N 8 0 R>>/DA(0 g /Helv 0 Tf)/F 4/FT/Sig/P 6 0 R/Rect[220 680 370 730]/Subtype/Widget/T(Signature1)/Type/Annot>>endobj
6 0 obj<</Annots[5 0 R]/Contents 9 0 R/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<</Font<</0<</BaseFont/Symbol/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>/1<</BaseFont/Arial/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>>>>>/Type/Page>>endobj
7 0 obj<</Type/Encoding/Differences[24/breve/caron/circumflex/dotaccent/hungarumlaut/ogonek/ring/tilde 39/quotesingle 96/grave 128/bullet/dagger/daggerdbl/ellipsis/emdash/endash/florin/fraction/guilsinglleft/guilsinglright/minus/perthousand/quotedblbase/quotedblleft/quotedblright/quoteleft/quoteright/quotesinglbase/trademark/fi/fl/Lslash/OE/Scaron/Ydieresis/Zcaron/dotlessi/lslash/oe/scaron/zcaron 160/Euro 164/currency 166/brokenbar 168/dieresis/copyright/ordfeminine 172/logicalnot/.notdef/registered/macron/degree/plusminus/twosuperior/threesuperior/acute/mu 183/periodcentered/cedilla/onesuperior/ordmasculine 188/onequarter/onehalf/threequarters 192/Agrave/Aacute/Acircumflex/Atilde/Adieresis/Aring/AE/Ccedilla/Egrave/Eacute/Ecircumflex/Edieresis/Igrave/Iacute/Icircumflex/Idieresis/Eth/Ntilde/Ograve/Oacute/Ocircumflex/Otilde/Odieresis/multiply/Oslash/Ugrave/Uacute/Ucircumflex/Udieresis/Yacute/Thorn/germandbls/agrave/aacute/acircumflex/atilde/adieresis/aring/ae/ccedilla/egrave/eacute/ecircumflex/edieresis/igrave/iacute/icircumflex/idieresis/eth/ntilde/ograve/oacute/ocircumflex/otilde/odieresis/divide/oslash/ugrave/uacute/ucircumflex/udieresis/yacute/thorn/ydieresis]>>endobj
8 0 obj<</BBox[0 0 150 50]/Length 0/Resources<<>>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj<</Length 597>>stream
BT 15 800 Td 40 TL /1 18 Tf
(PlainText = http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf)'
/1 16 Tf 40 TL (12  letters.)' 20 TL
(9)' 27 20 Td (letters.)'
-27 0 Td(A)' 25 20 Td(a)' 17 20 Td(a)' 18 20 Td(a)' 23 20 Td(a)' -72 20 Td(b)' 58 20 Td(b)' -35 20 Td(c)' 17 20 Td(d)' 26.5 20 Td(r)' -58 20 Td(r)'
40 TL
(goto page in another PDF)' 20 TL
(Also plain text = https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2)' 25 TL/1 11 Tf
120 140 Td(Sign and Secure this file.txt as a PDF with Adobe Reader)'
-5 -40 Td(or click https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html)'
ET
220 680 150 50 re
S
endstream
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000067 00000 n 
0000000126 00000 n 
0000000175 00000 n 
0000000251 00000 n 
0000000384 00000 n 
0000000568 00000 n 
0000001757 00000 n 
0000001858 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 10/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
2501
%%EOF


NOTE those trailing numbers will be wrong due to cut and pasting, However Adobe Reader will just edit the file for you anyway, as it does with signed or restricted Adobe PDF files too.
It does not matter if the box is seen 1st blank in a pdf viewer like Chrome (that cannot show the signature flag, as on its own does not sign PDF) or a reader that shows the signature flag, but due to JS security will not sign the file. They can all use a hyper text link to Adobe online signing.

View of the signed by Acrobat Reader and as seen in MS Edge.


Temporary 28 day Link to both files https://filetransfer.io/data-package/r0yiRVL9#link
